# Determine whether the $k^{th}$ smallest element in max-heap is greater than a given number

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

A set of numbers is stored in a **max-heap**. We want to find an algorithm with $O(k)$ time complexity to check if $k^{th}$ **smallest** element is greater than an arbitrary given number.

Comment: o(k) and O(k) mean different things. Do you actually mean O(k) instead?

Comment: Is the question about how do we implement such a heap, or is that, given a max-heap, how do we answer the question? If the second one, what do we know about the max-heap -- what operations can we do and what are their time complexities?

Comment: no, the heap is given. max-heap is a tree we can move on its elements.

Comment: excuse-me, I mean O(k).

Comment: I think we still don't know quite enough to answer the question.... We'd need to know the time complexity of each operation we can do on the heap, like findmin() or delete() or any other operations we can do. Also, it might matter how many things are currently in the heap. (For instance, an operation could run in time log(n) with $n$ the number of elements in the heap.)

Comment: Given max-heap has n elements, delete time complexity is O(log n). This max-heap is binary max-heap tree.

Comment: OK, but in the question you stated we want O(k) complexity. Does that mean this must be true independent of how many elements n are in the heap? Have you stated the question fully, and thought about what's needed to answer it?

Comment: Why you cross-post this?

Comment: I dont think you can do that. Even if you use min-heap.  Obviously, you would do that with a sorted list. I may post an answer later.

Comment: @AJed, for min heap is possible see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922648/how-we-can-find-kth-largest-element-from-a-max-heap-in-ok-time/4922925#4922925), but for max heap is impossible(IMO).

Comment: Aha ! so you want to check if there are $k$ elements greater than $x$ -- that's not what I understood at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt at disproof:

Suppose we have a max-heap of $n$ elements such that $k<\log n$ and I inform you that the $k^{th}$ smallest element is at the greatest depth of the tree. Without this detail, it could be elsewhere in the tree, but if we cannot solve this special case in time $O(k)$, the more  general case will take at least as much time - otherwise, we could use the algorithm for the general case to solve this specific case.

Note that in a max-heap, no node will give a bound on how *small* its children will be (but rather only how large). Thus, if we know the $k^{th}$ smallest is at the greatest depth, no node except those at the greatest depth will provide any information as to the location of the $k^{th}$ smallest element. There are $\log n$ children at the greatest depth and no particular ordering among them (which is one of the key characteristics which differentiates a heap from a sorted binary tree). Thus, you'll need to check all $\log n$ elements before you can determine whether the $k^{th}$ smallest is greater than an arbitrary number.

Hence, no comparison based algorithm with time complexity less than $O(\log n)$ exists to determine for a given max-heap whether the $k^{th}$ smallest element is greater than an arbitrary number.